# IOS keyboard direction and the direction of the status bar is not consistent, how to solve?

Tags: ios

The iOS status bar is set to horizontal screen display, but when the keyboard is still vertical screen, do not know how to solve?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some more information, screenshot?

Comment: supported orientations ?

Comment: Not enough information...Please provide some context to this question